# operand order is difference between xcrun otool and capstone, IDA

Tags: assembly, otool

So I have a simple hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

if we compile and get the binary on x86_64, and print its asm code and machine code:

asm code:

```
% xcrun otool -v -t a.out
a.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000f30    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f31    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f34    subq    $0x20, %rsp
0000000100000f38    leaq    0x4b(%rip), %rax
0000000100000f3f    movl    $0x0, 0xfffffffffffffffc(%rbp)
0000000100000f46    movl    %edi, 0xfffffffffffffff8(%rbp)
0000000100000f49    movq    %rsi, 0xfffffffffffffff0(%rbp)
0000000100000f4d    movq    %rax, %rdi
0000000100000f50    movb    $0x0, %al
0000000100000f52    callq   0x100000f68
0000000100000f57    movl    $0x0, %ecx
0000000100000f5c    movl    %eax, 0xffffffffffffffec(%rbp)
0000000100000f5f    movl    %ecx, %eax
0000000100000f61    addq    $0x20, %rsp
0000000100000f65    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f66    ret
```

and machine code:

```
% xcrun otool -s __TEXT __text a.out 
a.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
0000000100000f30 55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 20 48 8d 05 4b 00 00 00 c7 
0000000100000f40 45 fc 00 00 00 00 89 7d f8 48 89 75 f0 48 89 c7 
0000000100000f50 b0 00 e8 11 00 00 00 b9 00 00 00 00 89 45 ec 89 
0000000100000f60 c8 48 83 c4 20 5d c3
```

If I try to use keystone to convert 'mov rsp rbp', it gives me machine code:

> 0x48 0x89 0xec

which is different from otool's `48 89 e5`

After some trying and searching, I found it's that otool's operand order is left -> right, however, keystone or IDA treat the order is right -> left.

Can someone helps me, why otool print the reverse order?

I checked intel's asm handbook, the order is also right -> left. So I don't understand why otool print operands the other way.

Comment: It's "AT&T" or "gas" syntax, from GNU world (for example gcc  generates assembly in this syntax by default). `movq %rsp,%rbp` == `mov rbp,esp` in Intel syntax. Most of the GNU tools now have some way to switch them into intel syntax too, but I wouldn't believe they are ready to fully operate in such mode.

Comment: And after short googling, `otool` does not support Intel syntax.  You may want to check if something like `objdump -M intel -d` does help you...